# Using Forms and Get/Post in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a page called *wc-info.php* which is loaded using this function on a page called *plugin_admin.php*

```
public function iris_info()
{
    include('partials/wc-info.php');
}

public function get_gtin_woo_db($GTIN_Val)) {
    // get the gtin number
    $key = 'sku';
    $getTheMeta = get_post_meta($GTIN_Val, $key, TRUE);
    if ($getTheMeta != '') {
        $gtinSuccess = 'Yes';
    } else {
        $gtinSuccess = 'No';
    }
    return $gtinSuccess;
}
```

The partial looks like this:

```
<div class="welcome-panel-column">
    <form action="POST">
        <input type="text" action="" name="gtin_search">
        <input type="submit" action="" name="gtin_submit">
    </form>
</div
```

The problem is how do I pass the POST values to the *plugin_admin.php* page in wordpress? When submit is clicked, I need the page to be reloaded, and have POST passed to the function.

Comment: Have you tried add_action( 'init', 'some_function' ); and check for post variables. Then send data to your functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
function custom_function() {
    if ( isset( $_POST['gtin_search'] ) ) {
        // Update to the function which you are going to use
        get_gtin_woo_db($POST['gtin_search']);   
    } // end if
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_function' );
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: thanks, where would this function go however? In the root functions.php?

Comment: Either in the plugin or functions.php, I prefer functions.php.